# Python regex: Getting all numbers besides some which are followed by specific terms

Tags: python, regex

The goal is to get all the numbers from a text besides those which are either followed by or are trailing specific words/characters (including ignoring date).
What I am struggling with is negative lookbehind

For example: 4.5 $55 1,200 wordA 3 sometext 2 wordB sometext 4.3charA sometext charB21.6 sometext 11/10/22

In the sample numbers 3, 2, 4.3, 21.6 and the date 11/10/22 would be ignored

My attempt https://regex101.com/r/PQvtOl/1/

```
(\d*\b[\.,]?\d+)(?!\d*? (?:wordB))(?!\d*?(?:charA))((?!\b[charB/])(?!\d+))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
(?<!\d)\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?(?!\d)|\b(?:charB|wordA)\s*\d*[.,]?\d+|(?<!\d[.,])(?<!\d)(\d*[.,]?\d+)(?!\s*(?:wordB|charA)|[.,]?\d)
```

Get only those matches that are captured into capturing group #1. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kzSUn0/2). *Details*:

- `(?<!\d)\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?(?!\d)|` - a date-like string: no digit allowed immediately on the left, then one or two digits, `/`, one or two digits, `/`, and then two or four digits with no extra digit on the right allowed, or
- `\b(?:charB|wordA)\s*\d*[.,]?\d+` - a word boundary, then `charB` or `wordA`, zero or more whitespaces, zero or more digits, an optional dot or comma, one or more digits
- `|` - or (the next part is captured, and `re.findall` will only output those in the resulting list, the above ones will be discarded)
- `(?<!\d[.,])(?<!\d)(\d*[.,]?\d+)(?!\s*(?:wordB|charA)|[.,]?\d)` - no digit or digit and a `.` or `,` allowed immediately on the left, then zero or more digits, an optional `.` or `,` and one or more digits are captured into Group 1, and then the negative lookahead fails the match if there is `wordB`, `charA` or an optional `.` or `,` and a digit appear immediately on the right after any zero or more whitespaces.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/I23scS):

```py
import re
text = '4.5 $55 1,200 wordA 3 sometext 2 wordB sometext 4.3charA sometext charB21.6 sometext 11/10/22'
rx = r'(?<!\d)\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?(?!\d)|\b(?:charB|wordA)\s*\d*[.,]?\d+|(?<!\d[.,])(?<!\d)(\d*[.,]?\d+)(?!\s*(?:wordB|charA)|[.,]?\d)'
matches = re.findall(rx, text)
print( [ m for m in matches if m ] )
# => ['4.5', '55', '1,200']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! this would not work for a large number though, for example 120,990,000.

Comment: @jokol This is not about "large numbers", but number formats. There is nothing in your question that would hint at the number formats you expect to handle. Try `(?<!\d)\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?(?!\d)|\b(?:charB|wordA)\s*\d*[.,]?\d+|(?<!\d[.,])(?<!\d)((?:\d{1,3}(?:[.,]\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?)(?!\s*(?:wordB|charA)|[.,]?\d)`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kzSUn0/4). And [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/zWIpNH).

Comment: thanks! accepted the answer. Was curious though, what if I wanted to skip all 4 digit numbers (besides all the constraints above)? Spent some time and came up with this `(?!\d{4}[:\s\.,])(?<!\d[.,])(?<!\d)((?:\d+(?:[.,]\d{3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?)` but to no avail @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: @jokol Just add `\d{4}` alternative to the first pattern, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kzSUn0/5). It will make it match these 4-digit chunks and they will get omitted.